# Create Excel VBA code and button programmatically from C#

Tags: c#, excel, export, vba

I am in the middle of simple method, that saves my DataGridView into an Excel document (1 sheet only) and also adds VBA code and a button to run the VBA code.

```
public void SaveFile(string filePath)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        //Change  Workbook-properties.
        ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;

        // Storing header part in Excel.
        for (int i = 1; i < gridData.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            ExcelApp.Cells[1, i] = gridData.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        //Storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
        for (int row = 0; row < gridData.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            gridData.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = "Makro";
            for (int column = 0; column < gridData.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[row + 2, column + 1] = gridData.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(filePath);
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        ExcelApp.Quit();
    }
```

I only implemented DataGridView export.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Joel I could, with proper words, search again for the solution. I think that [this may be helpful](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;303872&Product=vcSne). Would you correct me or give a tip or two about what I should look for.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add a macro to the new workbook programmatically (from code)?

Comment: Yes. A new macro and a button that will run it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wrote a small example which **adds a new button** to an existing workbook and afterwards **add a macro which will be called when the button is clicked**.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
...

private static void excelAddButtonWithVBA()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"PATH_TO_EXCEL_FILE");
    Excel.Worksheet wrkSheet = xlBook.Worksheets[1];
    Excel.Range range;

    try
    {
        //set range for insert cell
        range = wrkSheet.get_Range("A1:A1");

        //insert the dropdown into the cell
        Excel.Buttons xlButtons = wrkSheet.Buttons();
        Excel.Button xlButton = xlButtons.Add((double)range.Left, (double)range.Top, (double)range.Width, (double)range.Height);

        //set the name of the new button
        xlButton.Name = "btnDoSomething";
        xlButton.Text = "Click me!";
        xlButton.OnAction = "btnDoSomething_Click";

        buttonMacro(xlButton.Name, xlApp, xlBook, wrkSheet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    xlApp.Visible = true;
}
```

And here we got the `buttonMacro(..)` method

```
private static void buttonMacro(string buttonName, Excel.Application xlApp, Excel.Workbook wrkBook, Excel.Worksheet wrkSheet)
{
    StringBuilder sb;
    VBIDE.VBComponent xlModule;
    VBIDE.VBProject prj;

    prj = wrkBook.VBProject;
    sb = new StringBuilder();

    // build string with module code
    sb.Append("Sub " + buttonName + "_Click()" + "\n");
    sb.Append("\t" + "msgbox \"" + buttonName + "\"\n"); // add your custom vba code here
    sb.Append("End Sub");

    // set an object for the new module to create
    xlModule = wrkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

    // add the macro to the spreadsheet
    xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Found this information within an KB article [**How To Create an Excel Macro by Using Automation from Visual C# .NET**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303872/en)